# UITableView Not Being Updated iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, delegates, datasource

I am downloading a string with the contents of a file online and separating these components by string into an array.

Once the download is finished I am calling a method to update my tableview to display these values.

```
- (void)updateTableView {
    tableView.delegate = self;
    tableView.dataSource = self;
}
```

Basically in this method I set the delegate and dataSource so the table view gets updated using this method...

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] init];
    cell.textLabel.text = [arrayDownloaded objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}
```

But the issue is is that the table view doesn't get updated until I "touch" the view.

Like all the data is loaded and the method has been called but not until I tap on anywhere on the screen does the tableview get updated?

Why is this and how can I make it update as soon as I set the delegate and dataSource?

-Henry

Comment: Add `[tableView reloadData];` in your `updateTableView`.

Comment: This isn't normal behavior, so you'll need to post more of your code so we can hopefully spot your issue.

Comment: @TimothyMoose Thanks for the reply, what code do you need?

Comment: Your view controller. If there isn't an obvious problem there, I think your best bet is to get your hands dirty and do some debugging.

Comment: @TimothyMoose How do I go about debugging this...? Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Put a breakpoint in `numberOfSectionsInTableView` and observe when it gets called. It should be getting called in `updateTableView`. The next step would depend on the result of this step.

Comment: @TimothyMoose That one gets hit, but when I put it in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` it doesn't get called until I scroll in the UITableView.

Comment: And then what does `numberOfRowsInSection` return? And you're verifying that this is happening under the call stack of `updateTableView`?

Comment: @TimothyMoose `50`... I don't see how that is important though...

Comment: Got it! Posting an answer. @TimothyMoose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured the solution. Rather than calling `[self updateTableView];` to call the following method...

```
- (void)updateTableView {
    [tableView reloadData];
}
```

I needed to do `[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(updateTableView) withObject:nil waitUntilDoneNO];`

Some people are calling this an iOS bug since if you are not on the main thread `numberOfRowsInSection` gets called but `cellForRowAtIndexPath` doesn't.

Just a strange thing that I saw happening in my app. Hopefully this helps future developers.

-Henry

Comment: UIKit code must always be run on the main thread. Failing to do so can result in undefined behavior. So I not sure how anyone could call the odd behavior an iOS bug. Glad you figured it out though.

Comment: you can also [tableView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadData) withObject:nil waitUntilDoneNO]

Answer (score 1):

Just reload the `tabledata` after finishing the downloading.

```
- (void)updateTableView 
{
    tableView.delegate = self;
    tableView.dataSource = self;
    [tableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: Still doesn't reload until I interact with the table view.

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't already doing this somewhere, you need to call `[tableView reloadData]` after you've applied your changes.